# Where should I store upcoming emails to send?

Tags: laravel, email, delay

I develop a Laravel app and want to send out an email two days after some user interaction.

Where should I store this "to send emails"?

In a new table? Or in a queue?

Or somewhere else? What is considered to be "best practice"? Why?

Comment: In the database, maintain the flag(ex:`is_notify` and `next_notify`) users table. And create a **Scheduler to run every day.** In the scheduler, write a function to get data from 2 days before and dispatch a JOB if `is_notify` sets to `true`.

Comment: There's no right answer, it depends on your circumstances (which is why open-ended questions like this are not considered suitable for SO and it is likely to be closed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  My 2c: why generate them early at all?  Set a timestamp flag on the appropriate record (eg `users.registered_at`), and run a [scheduled job](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling) every hour/day/x which checks the timestamps and finds 2-day-old registrations, generate and send them then.